# How to configure the columns of lightning data-table in lwc?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I want to configure my columns of lightning data-table.

This is my Apex.

```java
public with sharing class AccountsDataTableCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Account> getAllAccounts(String countryCode, String stateCode){
        if(countryCode!=null && stateCode!=null){
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account WHERE BillingCountryCode=:countryCode AND BillingStateCode=:stateCode LIMIT 20];
        }
        else{
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account];
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h3 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon class="slds-m-right_x-small" icon-name="standard:account" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            {AccountList}
        </h3>

        <c-filter-component-lightning oncountry={handleCountry} onstate={handleState}></c-filter-component-lightning>

        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-input name="enter-search" label="" type="search" placeholder="Search Account..."
                onchange={searchHandler}></lightning-input>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-m-top_x-small slds-box outerDesign">
            <div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height:10rem;width:75rem">
                <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={allAccounts} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column="true">
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';

import Account_List from '@salesforce/label/c.Account_List'
import getAllAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountsDataTableCtrl.getAllAccounts';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone' },
];
export default class ListComponentLightning extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    allAccounts = [];
    mainAllAccounts = [];
    country;
    state;
    columns = columns;
    AccountList = Account_List;
    
    connectedCallback() {
        this.getAllAccounts();
    }

    getAllAccounts(){
        getAllAccounts({countryCode: this.country, stateCode: this.state})
            .then(response => {
                this.allAccounts = response;
                this.mainAllAccounts = response;
            })
    }

    handleCountry(event) {
        const factor = event.detail.value;
        this.country = factor;
        this.getAllAccounts();
    }

    handleState(event) {
        const factor = event.detail.value;
        this.state = factor;
        this.getAllAccounts();
    }

    searchHandler(event) {
        let searchKey = event.detail.value.toLowerCase();
        let searchedTempAccounts = [];
        if (event.detail.value.length > 1) {
            for (const account of this.mainAllAccounts) {
                if (account.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey))
                    searchedTempAccounts.push(account);
            }
            this.allAccounts = searchedTempAccounts;
        }
        if (event.detail.value.length == 0)
            this.allAccounts = this.mainAllAccounts;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please, how should I configure the columns instead of hardcoding in JS.

Comment: Your code has `const columns`, and the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) here is robust. What are you hoping for, exactly? Hard coding the column definitions into the file is how it works.

Comment: I want that columns should be configurable like in metadata and then used that rather than the hardcoding in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the result if you don't want to code the columns

```
getAllAccounts(){
        getAllAccounts({countryCode: this.country, stateCode: this.state})
            .then(response => {
                this.allAccounts = response;
                this.mainAllAccounts = response;
                let Column = [];
                for(let item in response[0]){
                    Column.push({label : `${item}`, fieldName:`${item}`});
                }
                this.columns = Column;
            })
    }
```

Please let me know if it helps or you need anymore help!

Comment: This way every column will be of `type: 'text'` (the default) and the label will be the field's apiName, which is not optimal, especially for a custom field (the label will end with "__c")